# Declaring path to invoke a template file python27

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have tried using various declarations for trying to invoke the template file but for some reason the script is failing to pick the template from the location specified and loading the reporting contents to the template and then exporting it to a pdf format.
The code i have attached hereby :

```
 `#Build the html report using the html template and save to the set location
        output_from_parsed_template =  buildTemplate()
        with open(r"C:\python_report_scripts\anram_report.html","wb") as fh:
            fh.write(output_from_parsed_template)

        #Convert html to pdf
        subprocess.call('C:\omniformat\html2pdf995.exe r"C:\python_report_scripts\anram_report.html" r"C:\ANRAM_Requests\Working_folder\\'+sectionName+'.pdf"')

#Run a summary report when there is at least 1 section in the section list
if len(sectionInfo)>1:

    #Flag that this is a summary report
    summary = 1

    #Generate the Existing Map image
    MapExisting(summary)

    #Generate the Existing Risk Graph image
    RiskgraphExisting(summary)

    #Generate the New Map Image
    MapNew(summary)

    #Generate the New Risk Graph image
    RiskgraphNew(summary)

    #Generate the tabular results for the report
    populateResults(summary)

    #Indicate that the report is a summary, which then forms the report title
    #global sectionName
    sectionName = 'SUMMARY - '+sectionName

    #Build the html report using the html template and save to the set location
    output_from_parsed_template =  buildTemplate()
    with open(r"C:\python_report_scripts\anram_report.html","wb") as fh:
        fh.write(output_from_parsed_template)

    #Convert html to pdf
    subprocess.call('C:\omniformat\html2pdf995.exe r"C:\python_report_scripts\anram_report.html" r"C:\ANRAM_Requests\Working_folder\\'+sectionName+'.pdf"')`
```

So am i declaring it correctly ?

Please advise,

Answer (score 0):

This line looks weird:

```
#Convert html to pdf
subprocess.call('C:\omniformat\html2pdf995.exe r"C:\python_report_scripts\anram_report.html" r"C:\ANRAM_Requests\Working_folder\\'+sectionName+'.pdf"')`
```

You seem to be mixing up Python quoting, Python raw strings, with shell quoting and you still have some double backslashes around...

I suggest:

- Use `subprocess.check_call` instead, that way Python will report if there are any errors running the command.
- Pass it a list, instead of a string, that way it's more clear which argument is which and you don't depend so much on shell quoting and word splitting.
- Use raw strings consistently (`r'...'` or `r"..."`, either one is fine.)
- Use os.path.join to join paths!

So, putting it all together, try this instead:

```
# Convert html to pdf
subprocess.check_call([
    r'C:\omniformat\html2pdf995.exe',
    r'C:\python_report_scripts\anram_report.html',
    os.path.join(r'C:\ANRAM_Requests\Working_folder', sectionName + '.pdf')
])
```

I hope this solves the issue you're seeing... Or, if it doesn't, at least gives you a more meaningful error message that you can act on.

Comment: Thanks for that mate, Upon doing so.. the code below it goes in RED and says syntax error.. so is there something we missed in the syntax as u mentioned ?

Comment: Hey @abby, sorry, I forgot raw strings don't allow a backslash in the end... The most elegant way to solve that is to use `os.path.join(...)` to join your paths rather than string concatenation. I updated the post to do that. Remember you'll need to `import os` at the top of your code so it's available. I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Filipe, Actually got it working, i had to use forward slash..      'C:/omniformat/html2pdf995.exe "C:/python_report_scripts/anram_report.html" "C:/ANRAM_Requests/Working_folder/' + sectionName + '.pdf"')